# Blender 2.8 beta - How to bevel one edge of a rectangular cube?

Tags: blender, bevelled

Blender 2.80.74 beta

I have spent hours trying to figure this out. Watched videos that show how to round (using Bevel) the edges or edge of a uniform mesh cube. Works great.

But my mesh cube is rectangular 10x1x0.2 shape. And I can't get it to work. The edge seems to be beveled proportionally based on the size of the adjoining faces. I want non-proportional beveling. I know this is probably something easy I am missing, but I have spent hours and can't find the answer. I just want to evenly round this edge when looking at the cube.

```
+-----------+  (this edge)
|           |
+-----------+
```

[image]

Comment: I expect you scaled the cube in object mode. [Apply the scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91269/935).

Comment: I set the cube dimensions in object mode. Using N to set dimensions. With that said, I see now that 'Apply the scale' is a link. I will investigate. Thanks.

Comment: The third answer in 'Apply the scale' link by LeoNas worked! Thanks.